# After updating Joomla 3.9 - Class 'Joomla\CMS\Cache\Cache' not found

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache, fatal-error

I have updated Joomla to 3.9 and now I see this error every time I try to load the website:

> Error: Class 'Joomla\CMS\Cache\Cache' not found: Class 'Joomla\CMS\Cache\Cache' not found

Error reporting is already at maximum, I can't access the back-end as well. Tried to find a way to fix it, but only found dead-ends.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please, take our [tour](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/tour). Can you provide more details? Check if you have the file `Cache.php` in `[root]\libraries\src\Cache` or the folder `Cache` in  `[root]\libraries\src`